# Android Studio Transparency Bug in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

I'm having trouble while running android studio in Ubuntu 15.04 64bit.
All my windows screens (popups) are transparent. Thus, I can't see the popup content. I must launch the same window for 5 ou 6 time, to make it finally works.

Any idea about how to solve it. This problem just occurs with Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: Do they stay transparent or do they get opaque after a while? Also, **could** it be related to [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78848) ?

Comment: It keeps transparent forever. Sometimes, it draws just part of the screen.

Comment: I noticed this error on the console output.
[121995241]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - sun.awt.image.BufImgSurfaceData cannot be cast to sun.java2d.xr.XRSurfaceData

Answer (score 0):

The problems seems to lay within java JDK itself I would suggest to update to the latest version of the official Oracle release.

Comment: I agree with you. However, I'm already using 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)